# Another Application failed codesign verification error

Tags: iphone, codesign

I know this has been asked before but tried everything and no luck. Trying to upload my binaries using Application Loader and getting the above error.

Some interesting things for my case:

I accidentally have a space in my App name. Would this cause the code signing to fail?

Looked in the build log and the last entry is *** Warning: Defaulting to the standard codesign tool. Could this be the issue causing the problem? If so how do I solve it.

Behind a corporate firewall. I have access to the net but certain ports may be closed. Could this affect it?

Tried everything except revoking all the certificates mainly because I've just created them a few hours ago.

EDIT: OK, I've recreated the entire project, I've revoked all my certificates and recreated them and installed them, I've exported the last version from subversion to make sure subversion is not affecting it, used command line tool to compress it, made the target codesign the correct profile, made the project codesign both default and the distribution profile, tried a different net connection to make sure its not the firewall.

As you can see I've tried everything I can find and the stupid thing still wont work.

Any help?

Cheers

Comment: hi... have u fix this problem ? I also face this warning, although the app can be install on my device via xcode, but it failed to install my clients for testing ....

Comment: Nope, there are a bunch of possible fixes but none have worked. Though I have heard that if Apple has servers down it can give this same error. Have you recently created ur cert and is yours a new app?

Comment: Fixed it Robin, see below. You might have the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

K, This is incredibly annoying. After doing everything as I said in the question and doing some things twice decided to try the Application Loader on someone else's computer. Worked first time, didn't skip a beat.

Strange thing is I have the current Xcode (which I assume is where Application Loader comes from) and the other computer is running an old one. Perhaps the current one is broken?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue using XCode4. Turns out I needed to Edit the Scheme and specify that the Build Configuration for Archive was to the be the one for the one associated with the Distribution Provisioning Profile - in my case "App Store".

If you're having the same problem, that may be something to check.

Answer (score 0):

At the project level you want to set your code signing identity, **BUT LEAVE THE PROVISIONING PROFILE TO DEFAULT**.

Then at the target level you have to set both the code signing identity and the provisioning profile.

If you fail to do that the package will be signed but not interpreted correctly by itunes connect.

Comment: Under the code signing identity I set the provisioning profile. I don't know what you mean by set both of them?

Comment: take a look at this article: http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Provisioning-Profile-for-iPhone

Comment: Yeah sorry sorta miss read. I've created the provisioning profile and it comes up in the list, it also builds fine.

Answer (score 0):

I too had this problem, until I realized there's a different way to upload the apps now.

My 'release' Apps build as Archives

If you open the organizer and select 'Archives' at the top, there are 'Validate', 'Share', and 'Submit' buttons in the header info for your app.

Clicking on 'Validate' added my code signing information to the app (after logging in with the appropriate developer login)

Clicking on 'Submit' ran me through the same questions the Application Loader used to ask and uploaded the app without problems.  (again after signing in with the appropriate developer information)

Apparently when I updated to xcode 4, it just didn't remove the old application loader.

Answer (score 0):

Rudiger has worked around his problem by updating to the latest version of Xcode, but for others experiencing the error "Application failed codesign verification", see Apple's published list of potential causes at the following URL ["How do I resolve the error: Application failed codesign verification?"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TNTAG32)